# Using addChild error with coercion

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm attempting to use the addChild function in a game to have random objects appear and then move down a river to hit a controllable boat. I've watched several tutorials on youtube and think that I'm following the instructions properly but I'm getting the error #1067

> Implicit coercion of a value type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

I've set the barrel's class to barrel, and set to export the movie clip, what am I missing here?

```
{
    var bar:barrel = new barrel();
    addChild(barrel);
    bar.x = 200;
    bar.y = 200;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` is the instance, `barrel` is the class. Change `addChild(barrel)` to `addChild(bar);`

```
var bar:barrel = new barrel();
addChild(bar);
bar.x = 200;
bar.y = 200;
```

Comment: Also, best practice is to capitalize class names to distinguish them from variable names (giving `var bar:Barrel = new Barrel();` above).